# Pre-selected option in select Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have tried everything in the book. I just cant get option 1 value="1" User to be preselected. I am using angular website. If I remove ng-model="type" it gets preselected. but just cant get it working with ng-model="type" in it.

```html
<div class="form-group">
   <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control" ng-model="type">
       <option value="1" selected="selected">User</option>
       <option>Broadcasters</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this question about `AngularJS` or `Angular`?

Comment: angularjs sorry

Comment: Tag it accordingly then.

Comment: dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-model with ng-init to set the default selected value,

```
<select name="type" ng-model="selected" ng-init="selected='1'" id="type" class="form-control" ng-model="type">
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div class="form-group">
   <select name="type" ng-model="selected" ng-init="selected='1'" id="type" class="form-control" ng-model="type">
       <option value="1" >User</option>
       <option>Broadcasters</option>
   </select>
</div>
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As a good practice, `ng-init` **must** be used only when it's highly necessary, i.e: to initialize/alias something in `ng-repeat`. There's no point to use `ng-init` in this simple case. Check [**docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Also, you have two `ng-model` in `<select>` (in both markups).

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: You can use [ng-selected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) directive

```
<div class="form-group">
   <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control" ng-model="type">
      <option value="1" ng-selected="true">User</option>
      <option>Broadcasters</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

It happens because you pass Number to ng-model, instead input has string as value. Also it will work without ng-selected directive if you will pass String to ng-model.

Better to use: [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

```
<select ng-options="type as type.label for type in types" ng-model="currentType"></select>

$scope.types = [{
            id: 1,
            label: 'User'
        }, {
            id: 2,
            label: 'Broadcasters'
        }];

$scope.currentType = $scope.types[0]; //default type
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ng-value directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngValue) for numerical option values:

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app ng-init="type=1">

<div class="form-group">
   <select name="type" id="type" class="form-control" ng-model="type">
       <option ng-value="1">User</option>
       <option ng-value="2">Broadcasters</option>
   </select>
   <p>type = {{type}}</p>
</div>
</body>
```